# How Do I use CMU Flite TTS engine in my application?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, flite

I am developing an android application for text to speech in Indian languages and for that CMU Flite provides indic language voice databases. But I don't know how to use this plug in in my application. Please help me. In which way I can use Flite TTS engine in my own aplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build it from source [here](https://github.com/happyalu/Flite-TTS-Engine-for-Android)

I attempted this a few weeks ago and it failed to build. The scripts are outdated and it isn't set up for gradle.

There are also compatibility issues with some of the Native code.

So, it won't be easy to fix all of that.

Comment: Yupp, I did think of that for the first time but i was confused that would work or not. But it worked. Thanks

Comment: Yes. I used the necessary java classes from the original code and also need to install the cmu flite from the playstore.

Comment: @RiyaPatel Ah, OK. I thought you meant you successfully compiled it separately.